# Cannot link against core library when cross compiling

Tags: cross-compiling, rust

Having some trouble getting Rust to link to the core library on OS X targeting i686-unknown-linux-gnu:

```css
MacBook:rustboot alex$ make
rustc -O --target i686-unknown-linux-gnu --crate-type lib -o main.o --emit obj main.rs
main.rs:5:1: 5:19 error: can't find crate for `core`
main.rs:5 extern crate core;
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
make: *** [main.o] Error 101
```

main.rs looks like this:

```
#![no_std]
#![allow(ctypes)]
#![feature(lang_items)]

extern crate core;
use core::prelude::*;

#[no_mangle]
#[no_split_stack]
pub fn main() {
}
```

I suspect it is because I am trying to link to i686-unknown-linux-gnu but the core library doesn't exist for that platform. How do you install or build the libraries for that platform?

Comment: To be clear, you are deliberately trying to cross compile from OS X to Linux?

Comment: I'm trying to cross compile to write my own toy kernel, based on the code here: https://github.com/charliesome/rustboot I'm trying to get libcore to compile. The code above is the minimal code that highlights the problem. I'm going to try building from source with ./configure --target=i686-unknown-linux-gnu

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is caused by the core library not existing for the platform you're targeting. There's a few ways one might acquire it:

- use [rustup](https://rustup.rs/) — `rustup target add i686-unknown-gnu-linux` should do the trick
- get [cargo](http://doc.crates.io/) to do all the hard work by adding [`core-nightly`](https://crates.io/crates/core-nightly) to your `Cargo.toml`, and use `cargo build --target=...`. Unfortunately it seems it hasn't been updated for a while, but one can make a local package by copying `src/libcore` out of [the Rust repo](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust), adding a `Cargo.toml` and using a `path` dependency; in future, it is likely to be provided officially through crates.io too, but I have no idea how far away this is.
- download a Rust build for your desired target (e.g. the [corresponding nightly](http://static.rust-lang.org/dist/) to the one you have installed), extract the `lib/rustlib/` directory somewhere either automatically searched (`~/.multirust/toolchains/nightly-2015-01-18/lib/rustlib`), or anywhere and pass an `-L` flag to the compiler (I'm not 100% sure on the precise place the `-L` flag should point to, though).
- cross-compile Rust itself: checkout the repo, `./configure --target=$yourtarget` and then `make` should build you a compiler that can run on your current computer, but also create binaries that run on your desired target
- do manual cross-compilation of the crates you need, e.g. [zinc.rs](http://zinc.rs/) uses a [Rakefile](https://github.com/hackndev/zinc/blob/4a435501c9012414a03e2cdc759d0ccd9f93c145/Rakefile) that builds everything they want

The cargo route is definitely the easiest at the moment. The cross-compiling story will definitely get easier in future, e.g. making [multirust](https://github.com/brson/multirust) do all the complicated bits for the third possibility. However, both the third and fourth ways rely on being able to build `std` for your platform, which seems unlikely for kernel work.

(BTW, the [rlibc](https://crates.io/crates/rlibc) crate is useful/necessary for kernel work too.)

Comment: Got it working! Downloaded the nightly and copied the rustc-nightly-i686-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/i686-unknown-linux-gnu folder to /usr/local/lib/rustlib and it links. Thanks for your help.

Comment: See also these issues raised on [cargo](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/2158) and [multirust](https://github.com/brson/multirust/issues/20)

Comment: Another place to put libcore is in `$YOUR_PROJECT/.rust/lib/target.json/libcore.rlib`, and cargo will be happy.

Comment: rustlib from a different version seems to not work anymore.

Comment: @lilydjwg Hm, libs from different targets should still work, as long as they're the same compiler version (i.e. cross-compiling with rustc 1.6 will need to use the other 1.6 libraries).

Comment: @huon last time I tried a linux rustc with the official distributed windows, and it refused to compile because they came from different commits (the digit part of version are the same, but -dev vs. -nightly, and the hash is different). I also found the code comparing this.

Comment: @lilydjwg a downloaded rustc is not going the same as one built from source if it is built from a different commit. The commit hash is the "real" compiler version number (the 1.x.0 versioning really only applies for stable releases: the nightly compiler has ~45 builds for each of those numbers). Make the commits match and it should work (e.g. just download both).